# How can I display error bars an a datetime.datetime axis?

Tags: python, matplotlib, datetime, errorbar

I'm trying to make a plot with error bars along the time axis, ideally with adjustable upper/lower error limits. I've been using the datetime.datetime datatype to do this, which has been reliable until I've tried to implement error bars with matplotlib.pyplot.errorbar().

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np

dates = [datetime(1950,2,2,12),datetime(1950,2,2,15)]
data = [1,2]
date_err = [[datetime(1950,2,2,11,30),datetime(1950,2,2,14,30)], #arbitrary random dates/times
            [datetime(1950,2,2,12,30),datetime(1950,2,2,15,30)]]
test_err = [2,3]
fig, (ax1,ax2) = plt.subplots(2,1)
ax1.plot(dates,data,'k.')
ax1.tick_params(rotation = 45)
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace = 0.5)
ax2.errorbar(dates,data,xerr = test_err) #I tried both with date_err and test_err
ax2.errorbar(dates,data,xerr = date_err)
```

which gives the plot:

[image]

I tried both using a list shape (2,N) with format [[low1,low2...lowN],[high1,high2...highN]] with datatype datetime.datetime() but I recieve the error:

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'datetime.datetime'

When using integers/floating point numbers like in test_err, I get the error:

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'datetime.datetime' and 'int'

Can anyone either suggest an alternative way to plot with dates/times or a way to implement error bars along the temporal axis? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `timedelta` as the errors. I don't know what your desired errors are, but you can easily adjust that.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

plt.close("all")

dates = [datetime(1950, 2, 2, 12), datetime(1950, 2, 2, 15)]
data = [1, 2]
test_err = [timedelta(minutes=30), timedelta(hours=2)]

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, 1)
ax1.plot(dates, data, 'k.')
ax2.errorbar(dates, data, xerr=test_err, capsize=3)
ax1.tick_params(rotation=45)
ax2.tick_params(rotation=45)
fig.tight_layout()
fig.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you want [`timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta):

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

test_err = [timedelta(hours=2), timedelta(hours=3)]
ax2.errorbar(dates, data, xerr=test_err)
```

Output:

[image]